# Dplyr can't filter min grouped value with na.rm = TRUE

Tags: r, dplyr

I am unable to get dplyr (v. 1.1.2) to keep only minimum row values for a group of two variables when there is a NULL value in the group. Using na.rm = TRUE is resulting in a whole group being dropped instead of ignoring the null in that group and keeping the minimum of the two non-nulls:

```
# Original data frame
my_df <-
structure(list(uid = c("id100", "id100", "id100", "id100", "id200", 
"id200", "id200", "id200", "id300", "id300", "id300", "id300"
), cat = c("franklin", "franklin", "aretha", "aretha", "franklin", 
"aretha", "aretha", "aretha", "franklin", "franklin", "aretha", 
"franklin"), food = c("fish", "beef", "chicken", "chicken", "beef", 
"pork", "turkey", "fish", "beef", "pork", "chicken", "beef"), 
    date = structure(c(8674, 8703, 8685, 8689, 8675, 8677, 8680, 
    8691, 8701, NA, 8698, 8697), class = "Date")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

Attempt to filter and keep min values for each group:

```
# Group by two variables, filter
new_df <-
  my_df %>%
  group_by(uid, cat) %>%
  filter(date == min(date), na.rm = TRUE)
```

Result:

```
  uid   cat      food    date      
  <chr> <chr>    <chr>   <date>    
1 id100 franklin fish    1993-10-01
2 id100 aretha   chicken 1993-10-12
3 id200 franklin beef    1993-10-02
4 id200 aretha   pork    1993-10-04
5 id300 aretha   chicken 1993-10-25
```

Desired result:

```
  uid   cat      food    date      
  <chr> <chr>    <chr>   <date>    
1 id100 franklin fish    1993-10-01
2 id100 aretha   chicken 1993-10-12
3 id200 franklin beef    1993-10-02
4 id200 aretha   pork    1993-10-04
5 id300 aretha   chicken 1993-10-25
6 id300 franklin beef    1993-10-24
```

Comment: should be `filter(date == min(date, na.rm = TRUE))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `slice_min` with option `na_rm = TRUE`

```
my_df %>%
    slice_min(date, by = c(uid, cat), na_rm = TRUE)
```

which gives

```
    uid      cat    food       date
1 id100 franklin    fish 1993-10-01
2 id100   aretha chicken 1993-10-12
3 id200 franklin    beef 1993-10-02
4 id200   aretha    pork 1993-10-04
5 id300 franklin    beef 1993-10-24
6 id300   aretha chicken 1993-10-25
```

Answer (score 0):

na.rm should be put in the `min`.

```
new_df <-
  my_df %>%
  group_by(uid, cat) %>%
  filter(date == min(date, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively please try

```r
library(tidyverse)

my_df %>% group_by(uid, cat) %>% fill(date) %>% filter(date==min(date)) %>% ungroup()


# A tibble: 6 × 4
  uid   cat      food    date      
  <chr> <chr>    <chr>   <date>    
1 id100 franklin fish    1993-10-01
2 id100 aretha   chicken 1993-10-12
3 id200 franklin beef    1993-10-02
4 id200 aretha   pork    1993-10-04
5 id300 aretha   chicken 1993-10-25
6 id300 franklin beef    1993-10-24
```